Android Manifest file in Unity. Error when uploading to Google Play. How can I fix that?
I want to update my games to API 34, using Unity 2019.1.0f1. With my 2 projects everything goes smooth, after building my project I've uploaded it without problem, but one project is stubborn.
After uploading .aab I get this error:

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set.

I know I have to put that property in manifest and I've done that but after building .aab not seeing it?
I don't know, even after building my project and checking temp folder the manifest shows android:exported="true".
Thanks in advance for help.
I've tried to export that project and copy manifest from Android Studio, also tried to put another manifest in Plugins > Android instead of only in Plugins>Android > GoogleMobileAdsPlugin
Tried to add .androidlib in that ads plugin folder, again error. Last thing I tried is updating to 2020 even 2021, after fixing every error about depreciated code, same no android:exported=true for .aab

Android SDK 34 is supported on 2021.3.41f1+ versions of Unity. Try upgrading your unity version
